# python check string for emptieness - is this the elegant way

Tags: python

```
if var is not None and var !="" and var !=" ":
   # todo
```

can I write it like this?:

```
if var: 
   # todo
```

var is only String type.

Comment: @aug Not since OP wants whitespace to count as empty strings as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to filter out space-only string (`"  "`):

```
if var and var.strip():
    # ...
```

Becasue string that contain spaces is evaludated as True if used as predicate:

```
>>> bool("")
False

>>> bool("  ")
True
```

Comment: I think `if var.strip():` is equivalent to that.

Comment: @ShashankGupta: Not if `var` could be `None`.

Comment: Although obviously if `' '` is the *only* whitespace string that should be considered false, whereas `' ' * 2` or `'\t'` should be considered true as in the code in the question, then the answer is different :-)